# Django creating queryset filtered by group member ship results in error

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to create a queryset. the class is Allocation and has 2 properties (and some others) user and group. The user and group are the default django auth User and Group. So the user has a many to many relationship with group.

```
class Allocation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

The queryset should be containing only those objects with a group of which the user is a member. The attempt below results in

```
TypeError at /allocation/
'SQLEvaluator' object is not iterable
```

Attempt:

```
queryset=Allocation.objects.select_related().filter(user__groups__contains=F('group'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `__contains`.

```
Allocation.objects.select_related().filter(user__groups=F('group'))
```